# Python обработать каждый элемент списка списков в одну строку

Tags: python, list, tuple

Есть список:

```
a = [("a", [2,4]), ("b", [1,3]), ("с",[3,8])]
b = [i for i in a if i%2 ==0 ]
print(b)
```

Как сделать, чтоб он проверял каждый элемент в каждом списке на четность и вывел только те списки, где есть только четные? Код должен быть в одну строку
Нужный вывод:  ('a', [2,4])

Сам смог сделать только проверку:

```
l = list(map(lambda x: (x[0], functools.reduce(lambda a,b: b%2 != 1, x[1])),l))
```

Вывод:

```
[('a', False), ('b', False), ('c', True)]
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
b = [tpl for tpl in a if all(x%2==0 for x in tpl[1])]
```

результат:

```
In [197]: b
Out[197]: [('a', [2, 4])]
```